# Youtube Data API v3 - Get video feeds of auto-generated channels

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use auto-generated channel Ids as example below...

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UCrfjym-5AEUY2QzXsddRIQA&fields=items(id%2Csnippet)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

...to access their video contents. But seems I cannot make use of the `part: 'snippet,contentDetails'`, or `filter:'uploads'` filtering method as I use for getting normal user channel Ids before grabbing their playlistItems. Is there a simple method to display video feed or playlist contents of an auto-generated channel? I use the gapi.client instead of the url. Thx for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINAL UPDATE**:

Here is my solution for auto-generated Topic-based channel ids, since I'm using
`gapi.client`, here's what works (relevant code only - URL samples below):

```
function requestUserUploadsPlaylistId(pageToken) {
var itemId = $("#YOUR-TEXT-INPUT").val(CHANNEL-ID); // Topic-based channel Id
var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.list({ // Use playlists.list
channelId: itemId, // Return the specified channel's playlist
part: 'snippet',
filter: 'items(id)' // This gets what you only need, the playlist Id
});
request.execute(function(response) {
playlistId = response.result.items[0].id;
requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, pageToken); // Now call function to get videos
});
}

function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, pageToken) {
var requestOptions = {
playlistId: playlistId,
part: 'id,snippet',
maxResults: 6
};

var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);
request.execute(function(response) { // playlistItems.list is used here
. . .
```

Here's the URL sample of auto-generated Topic-based Id which grabs its playlist id:
[GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=HC9m3exs6zk1U&fields=items%2Fid&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list?part=snippet&channelId=HC9m3exs6zk1U&fields=items%252Fid&_h=47&) // Outputs sample playlist Id: LP9m3exs6zk1U

Now here's the URL sample using that playlist Id to get the videos from the auto-generated Topic-based channel Id:
[GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=5&playlistId=LP9m3exs6zk1U&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&maxResults=5&playlistId=LP9m3exs6zk1U&_h=53&) // Outputs video data you want.

**Remember**, Topic-based channel Ids come in different lengths, the above samples support current available lengths.

Hope This Helps!

Comment: This seemed like a good approach, but I noticed some videos on the home screen of the auto-generated channel are actually missing from the playlist(s).
Have you noticed this as well? How did you go about it (if you still remember)?